# Short lambda being split by clang-format, even with AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine

Tags: c++, lambda, clang-format, list-initialization

I have this code block:

```
int main() {
    SomeType something1(
        [](const Input& i) -> Output { return Output {1, 2}; },
        [](const Input& i) -> Output { return Output {1, 2}; }
    );

    SomeType something2(
        [](const Input& i) -> Output { return Output (1, 2); },
        [](const Input& i) -> Output { return Output (1, 2); }
    );
}
```

And when I try to `clang-format` with these settings:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
```

It produces this output (note that `something1` and `something2` get formatted differently):

```
int main() {
  SomeType something1(
      [](const Input &i) -> Output {
        return Output{1, 2};
      },
      [](const Input &i) -> Output {
        return Output{1, 2};
      });

  SomeType something2([](const Input &i) -> Output { return Output(1, 2); },
                      [](const Input &i) -> Output { return Output(1, 2); });
}
```

I've isolated the issue to the brace initialiser in `something1`.

- How do I make clang-format output both `something1` and `something2` in the style of `something2`
- Why is clang-format parsing/treating them differently? (For my own understanding)

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error when I was making the example. Behaviour is the same with and without the semicolons (but the semicolons are correct)

Comment: *"Why is clang-format parsing/treating them differently?"* I would say "bug".